# For-loop vs foreach vs apply and the fastest objects for data manipulation?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, optimization, apply

I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable than myself can help optimize this code. I've tried a number of methods, including foreach with doparallel (and snow) and compiler, but I think there may be simpler ways to improve the code, such as changing dataframes to datatables/matrices, and perhaps pre-loading blank objects instead of concatenating vectors in a loop.

Most of the variables listed below must be allowed to change in length depending on previous steps in the pipeline. Dimensions listed are taken from 1 example to show relative magnitude.

`s.ids` = a factor with length 66510. Haven't noticed a difference in speed when changed to a character vector.

`g.list` = a character vector with length 978.

`l_signatures` = a 978x66511 matrix.

`d_g_up` and `d_g_down` = small dataframes (nx10, n ranging from 5-200) with metadata related to `g.list`

`c_score_new()` computes a score. It's complex enough that it's essentially unchangeable in this scenario. It expects `e_signature` to have 2 columns, 1 made of `g.list` ("ids"), and the other as corresponding "rank"s generated by: `rank(-1 * l_signatures[,as.character(id)], ties.method="random")`

```
for (id in s.ids) {
    e_signature <- data.frame(g.list,
                              rank(-1 * l_signatures[, as.character(id)],
                                   ties.method="random"))    
    colnames(e_signature) <- c("ids","rank")
    d_scores <- c(d_scores, c_score_new(d_g_up$Symbol, d_g_down$Symbol, e_signature))
}
```

Total, this takes 5-10 minutes to compute, with 3-5 minutes attributable to the generation of e_signature, which is not computationally complex. That's where I suspect optimization might be of the most benefit.

If we did a loop to generate `e_signature` in a more efficient way and combined results into 1 object (978x66510) before doing `c_score_new()`, it might be faster?

I'm having trouble working out the details, and I'm not confident this is the best method anyhow. So before I chased this wild goose, I thought the community might be able to steer me in the best direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest amount of time is taken by `rank`. It is possible to reduce computation time by more than 50%, i.e. change `base::rank` with `for` loop to `Rfast::colRanks`, please see below:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(Rfast)

n <- 978
m <- 40000 #66510

x <- matrix(rnorm(n * m), ncol = m)

microbenchmark(
  Initial = {
    for (i in 1:ncol(x)) { 
      base::rank(x[, i], ties.method = "random")
    }
  },
  Optimized = {

    colRanks(x, method = "min")
  },
  times = 1
)
```

Output:

```
Unit: seconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   Initial 8.092186 8.092186 8.092186 8.092186 8.092186 8.092186     1
 Optimized 3.397526 3.397526 3.397526 3.397526 3.397526 3.397526     1
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comment! I tried this a couple of times yesterday but saw no improvement. I tried again today after moving into an RMD to hopefully exclude some bugs, but got the same thing - no improvement. Old times: 7.4 - 7.9 minutes, new times: 7.8-7.9 minutes. I think the variance is just random. I do think you're on to something. I'll have to figure out how my objects are different than yours.

Comment: I noticed a huge performance gain in terms of generating the df like you show above. It's almost generated instantly. Unfortunately, when I run the analysis (c_score_new()), I have to take columns from that df in a loop still, and I lose 100% of that time (still totaling ~7.5min). I wish I could give you more than an upvote; I really appreciate you looking at this for me!

Comment: Unfortunately without further details on `c_score_new ` function it is quite difficult to optimize. E.g. please check as well the reason you are submitting in the cycle `d_g_up$Symbol`, `d_g_down$Symbol `- but they are unmutable in `for` loop.

Comment: Moreover you can use `data.table` package which allows additional fast functions including hash calculations.